# Monitoring a installation

Tags: monitoring

I have an installation file that shall be run with root privileges. I have created a linux sandbox and would like to know what files are actually created and which are modified by such install script.

I cannot see the contents of the installation file because it's compiled.

Any software that can monitor this?

Comment: What kind of file is this?  It could be a `*.deb`, `*.rpm`, `*.tar.xz`.  These are standard formats for linux packages.  If it's just an install script (like `install.sh`), these are usually ascii files.  In that case, can you `cat` the contents and add it to this question?

Comment: Hello @Stewart, as I said: I cannot see the contents of the installation file because it's compiled.

It must have been compiled with a C/C++ compiler because looking at it binary contents I clearly see som libc references.

Comment: That's very non-standard.  I'm afraid the only one who can help you is the author of that installation binary.

Comment: I completely sympathize with you.  When I install something I also like to know what it's doing, especially if I'm expected to run a binary with root permissions.  The normal solution to this in the *nix world is to have access to source code.  Failing that, installation packages like `*.deb` can be unpacked and the maintainer scripts can be inspected in ascii. This at least lets you inspect what's going on when root privileges are being used. If someone's asking you to run a binary with root permissions and won't give you source code, that's usually a bad sign.

Comment: It's mostly closed source enterprise software that takes this approach, according to personal experience. Acronis has something similar to install their snakeoil suite.